# Jquery slide tab from right to left function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to slide a tab from right to left using this code but i am not achieving  my initial goal. this is the jquery file. I tried implementing animate direction left but it only gave me errors.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {
        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () { 

            $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing); 

            var toggleClick = $(this);

            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');

            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {

                if(options.changeText==1){
                    $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                }
            });

            return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here:

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

You're declaring `options` twice, in the function as a parameter, and as a variable inside the function. This is a source of problems. Just rename it to `opts` for example:

```
var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

Comment: alright, great advice i didnt notice that small mistake. but how will i go about adding an option to slide to left?

Comment: No small mistake, pretty serious I'd say. Look http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/5kXQj/. To slide your tab from the sides you were right about animate, that's what you should use. Usually you'd animate the `width` of the tab and not the `left` property...